# How to show element only if an array have two ore more items with angularjs ng-show?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array of items which could be empty, have one item ore two+ items.
Now if i want to show the element i use the simple ng-show event.

```
<div ng-show="scopeName">
...
</div>
```

So, if the pageSlides has items the div will be printed else it will not.

Now i would like to edit this show the div printed when the item has 2 ore more items.

I am trying with this but it doesn't work:

```
<div ng-show="pageSlides.length > 1"> (or any number)
...
</div>
```

I would love to some help on this.

Thank you!

UPDATED, here's my code:

```
myApp
  .controller(
    'controllerName', 
    [
      '$rootScope',
       '$scope', 
       '$routeParams',
       'Api', 
       function($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, Api) {

      var pageSlug = $routeParams['pageSlug']; 

      $scope.init = function() {

          $scope.singlePage = [];
          $scope.pageSlides = [];
          Api.get(
              'site/' + $rootScope.config.api.propertyId + '/page/' + pageSlug                  
          ).then(                        
              function(data) { 
                    $scope.singlePage = data.page;
                    $scope.pageSlides = $scope.singlePage['media'];
              }
          );

      }

      $scope.init();  

}])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code, it should work:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-show="array.length > 2">I'm visible</div>
    <div ng-show="array.length > 3">I'm not visible</div>
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.array = [
        {id: 1},
        {id: 2},
        {id: 3}
    ];
}
```

This is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7433/) with working example.

I want to note, that your question's code has a mistake: scopeName.leng**ht** > 1

I think, that it would be better: scopeName.leng**th** > 1  :)

Comment: That was a misspell here, sorry about that. But it still not working.

Comment: @VassilisPits, have you seen my JSFiddle example? This should works. Could you provide your code for us?

Comment: Thank you, i feel VERY stupid, that was a misspell indeed and a cache issue later. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/T3m8Z/7/)

```
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-show="items.length">I am showing, items array is not empty</div><br />
       <div ng-show="items.length > 1">I am showing, items array has more than one record</div><br />
       </div>
</div>



var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
     $scope.items = ["Apple", "Orange"];
});
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. My array comes from a services, is this a problem?

Comment: Could you please update the code in your post..so that we can understand better.

Comment: Please ensure that pageSlides response is an array? and check the controller name in your view..I did not see any error in your code.

Comment: Thank you Asik, that was a misspell from my (18hours straight on pc need rest :P). I choose Artyoms answer just because he answer first. But thank you too!